# How to make Maple 15 plot VolumeOfRevolution with implicity function?

Tags: maple

Suppose I have two functions f(y) and g(y), how do I plot the surface rotated about the axes in Maple? Assume you cannot write f(y) or g(y) in terms of x. Maple only allows g(x) and f(x)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to revolve the region between $x=f(y)$ and $x= g(y)$ around the $x$ axis?  What you can do is rotate the region between $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ around the $y$ axis, and then change the orientation using **transform** in the **plottools** package.  For example:

> f:= y -> 2 - y^2;
>
> g:= y -> 1 + y^2;
>
> with(Student[Calculus1]): with(plottools):
>
> A:= VolumeOfRevolution(f(x), g(x), x = 0 .. 1/sqrt(2), output = plot, axis = horizontal,  caption = "", scaling=constrained, axes=frame):
>
> transform((x,y,z) -> [z, y, x])(A);

[image]